# Rtmp protocal Is not supporting in android

Tags: java, android, rtmp

Can anyone help me rtmp url is not working where i tried lot of rtmp url but its not working and am using vitamio library...

```
    if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vitamio_videoView);
    path = "rtmp://sonlifelivefs.fplive.net/sonlifelive-live/";

    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();

    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I don't really know about Vitamio library, but for RTMP itself is not natively supported by android's VideoView

Comment: I have checked Vitamio website, and they announced that they support RTMP, maybe you could check if the VideoView you declare here is the VideoView from Vitamio, and not Android's VideoView

Comment: No i used videoview from vitamio only...

Comment: <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vitamio_videoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />